# 3D surface plot using 3 variables that have no function

Tags: r, surface

I'm trying to build a surface plot on R with this data:

```
days    ng de Deltametrina/abelha   mortality
1   0.005833333 0.2
1   0.0075  0.066666667
1   0.01    0.066666667
1   0.109375    0.466666667
1   0.093333333 0.4
1   0.21    0.533333333
1   0.02    0.066666667
1   0.028636364 0.266666667
1   0.077777778 0.4
1   0.064166667 0.2
1   0.105   0.2
1   0.126388889 0.4
1   0   0.333333333
2   0.56    0.333333333
2   0.040384615 0.133333333
2   0.5 0.066666667
2   1.3125  0.466666667
2   1.5 0.533333333
2   2.45    0.571428571
2   1.507692308 0.133333333
2   0   0.2
2   1.555555556 0.4
2   1.925   0.230769231
2   3.675   0.2
2   0.758333333 0.454545455
2   0   0.3125
3   0.42    0.333333333
3   0.735   0.285714286
3   0.466666667 0.142857143
3   0   0.5625
3   1.8 0.533333333
3   2.858333333 0.571428571
3   1.12    0.0625
3   0   0.333333333
3   2.722222222 0.4
3   5.133333333 0.5
3   4.2 0.466666667
3   7.9625  0.714285714
3   0   0.333333333
4   0.42    0.333333333
4   0.735   0.285714286
4   0.933333333 0.142857143
4   1.5 0.5625
4   1.8 0.533333333
4   5.39    0.642857143
4   1.493333333 0.0625
4   0   0.333333333
4   2.333333333 0.4
4   3.85    0.4
4   4.9 0.6
4   6.066666667 0.625
4   0   0.357142857
1   0.175   0
1   0.196875    0
1   0.2625  0
1   0.328125    0
1   0.39375 0
1   0.49    0
1   0.7 0
1   0.45    0
1   0.7 0
1   0.721875    0
1   1.2 0.066666667
1   1.240909091 0.266666667
1   0   0
2   0.21875 0
2   0.328125    0
2   0.4375  0
2   0.538461538 0.1875
2   0.39375 0
2   0.7 0.066666667
2   0.7 0
2   0.969230769 0.071428571
2   1.076923077 0.071428571
2   1.283333333 0.25
2   0.7 0.142857143
2   3.033333333 0.6
2   0   0
3   0.233333333 0.0625
3   0.42    0.0625
3   0.7 0
3   0.291666667 0.25
3   0.39375 0
3   0.875   0.066666667
3   0.8 0.125
3   0.675   0.066666667
3   0.026923077 0.1875
3   1.05    0.3125
3   0   0.1875
3   4.55    0.75
3   0   0
4   0.2 0.125
4   0.35    0.0625
4   0.2625  0
4   0.318181818 0.3125
4   0.484615385 0.133333333
4   0.525   0.066666667
4   0.861538462 0.133333333
4   0.9 0.066666667
4   0.269230769 0.1875
4   1.4 0.3125
4   1.145454545 0.3125
4   0   0.75
1   0.21875 0.058823529
1   0.185294118 0
1   0.4375  0
1   0.514705882 0
1   0.56    0.117647059
1   0.6125  0.058823529
1   0.525   0
1   0.7875  0.058823529
1   1.029411765 0
1   0.256666667 0.166666667
1   0.646153846 0.235294118
1   1.4 0.1875
1   0   0
2   0.13125 0.058823529
2   0.185294118 0
2   0.35    0
2   0.28    0.117647059
2   0.016333333 0.117647059
2   0.037333333 0.0625
2   0.0196875   0.058823529
2   0.021875    0.058823529
2   0.032083333 0.333333333
2   0.381818182 0.352941176
2   0   0.058823529
3   0.175   0.058823529
3   0.065625    0.058823529
3   0.2625  0
3   0   0.588235294
3   0.175   0.176470588
3   0.175   0.058823529
3   0   0.058823529
3   0.4375  0.058823529
3   0.035   0.352941176
3   0.0525  0.529411765
3   0   0.058823529
4   0.13125 0.058823529
4   0.39375 0.058823529
4   0.373333333 0.0625
4   1.26    0.705882353
4   0.188461538 0.235294118
4   0.35    0.058823529
4   0.057272727 0.352941176
4   0.75    0.176470588
4   0.427777778 0.470588235
4   0.038181818 0.45
4   0   0.117647059
```

However, I have found only R functions that use z in function to X and Y. And this is not my case. I'm not sure if my data will be good to visualization, because I'm new here and a just copy and paste my data here. Sorry if it seems messy!

Comment: What is your X,Y,Z in this case ?